# SQL ORDER BY dilemma with numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table which holds a varchar datatype. It holds 128 characters max.

I'm trying to order it alphabetically, and it works out fine, except for one little thing.

When I try to save a mixture of numbers and letters, it returns the 'literal' alphabetical order, which means 11 comes first before 2.

I have read almost all of the answers in the internet, but they are all workarounds that cannot work specifically for my problem.

Examples of values I want to put in order

```
Apartment
House
Dog
Cat
18 years old
2 years old
1 year old
```

But I want it to look like this.

```
1 year old
2 years old
18 years old
Apartment
Cat
Dog
House
```

It spans on a large database and I can't just split the numerical values apart from the text ones.

Also users who can use the program can modify it with Alphanumeric characters.

Any suggestions about my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Which SQL database are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: In what order do you want to put your data? Anyway, start with reading this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies

Comment: -1 for some of the worst data I've seen

Comment: I am currently using MySQL for this particular project. The data on the output must be in alphabetical-numeric order, if that's even a term. :) Which means 1 goes first then 2 before 11, then after all the numbers, that's when the pure text value follows :)

Comment: Please update your post to show how you would like your sample data to be sorted as. Do you want '1 Year Old' before '2 years old', how do you expect that to work?

Comment: Yes I want those with numeric to go first, to work on both alphabetical and numeric order. So that 1 goes first before 2 and 2 goes first before 11 and 11 goes first before 'Apartment'. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this as follows...

First, write an expression to convert the numeric stuff to integers, something like

```
select CAST(SUBSTRING(<field>',1,instr(<field>',' ') as INT),<field>
```

I would then use a UNION ALL statement, something like this

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(<field>',1,instr(<field>',' ') as INT),<field>,A.*
FROM <table> A
WHERE <field> LIKE <regular expression to get fields beginning with numbers>
UNION ALL
SELECT 999999,<field>,A.*
FROM <table> A
WHERE <field> NOT LIKE <regular expression to get fields beginning with numbers>
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

The numbers will appear first, in numeric order.  Sine all of the alpha data has the same numeric key, it will appear sorted alphabetically after the numbers... Just be sure to make the alpha dummy key (999999) is large enough to be after all the numeric ones...

I don't have mySQL on this machine, but hopefully this gives you enough of a start to solve it

Comment: yes. this works fine if the numbers are at the first part of the stack. how about if you have Super 8 or Super 16 values? Super 8 has to come first before super 16. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could possible use mySQL regex parser to create a regular expression that will return just the numeric portion of the string, and adapt both the cast and the where expression to use it instead.  I am not that familiar with mySQL's regex's though to help you with that.  You might want to post a question asking for a mySQL Regex to remove all numeric characters, and you will probably get several responses.   Good luck

Comment: @Nathan In this case I suggest to create a user defined function which parses a given string for ALL occurrences of numbers and replaces all these numbers by a fixed-width representation, like 000000000012. (Beware of special-cases like dates.) Use this function in your order-by clause.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something I tried in SQL Server. It's neither elegant nor fit for production, but it may give you an idea.

```
SELECT StringValue, 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(StringValue, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos) AS INT) AsNumber,
    SUBSTRING(StringValue, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos) NumberToken,
    SUBSTRING(StringValue, EndPos, 1000) Rest,
    StartPos, 
    EndPos
FROM    
    (SELECT 
        StringValue,
        PATINDEX('[0-9]%', StringValue) StartPos,
        PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', StringValue) EndPos
    FROM 
        (SELECT 'abc123xyz' StringValue
        UNION SELECT '1abc'
        UNION SELECT '11abc'
        UNION SELECT '2abc'
        UNION SELECT '100 zasdfasd') Sub1
    ) Sub2
ORDER BY AsNumber, Rest
```

Result:

```
StringValue       AsNumber        NumberToken  Rest            StartPos     EndPos
abc123xyz                 0                    abc123xyz               0          1
1abc                      1                  1 abc                     1          2
2abc                      2                  2 abc                     1          2
11abc                    11                 11 abc                     1          3
100 zasdfasd            100                100  zasdfasd               1          4
```

Comment: +1. If OP wants elegant it should start with the initial design, not with the retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably get away by doing something like this:

```
order by right(replicate(' ',30)+Column_name,30)
```

Comment: still, It doesn't work. it still shows 16, 30 and 75 before 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this order by:

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',128)+value,128)
```

My test:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
value VARCHAR(128)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES('Apartment'),
('House'),
('Dog'),
('Cat'),
('18 years old'),
('2 years old'),
('1 year old'),
('12 horses'),
('1 horse')


SELECT * FROM @T
ORDER BY RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',128)+value,128)
```

RESULTS:

```
Cat
Dog
House
1 horse
12 horses
Apartment
1 year old
2 years old
18 years old
```

If you find a case that this doesn't work please post it along with the sort order you would like and I can see if there's a fix.